# addFieldToFilter with like removing some characters in query

Tags: catalog, catalogsearch, collection-filtering

I have saved a url in the db. The url is: http://localhost/magento/index.php/electronics/cameras.html?cat=25&price=-100

```
$url = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getStateUrl();
$filterstate = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFilterState();
$inc= 1;
  foreach($filterstate as $key=>$value):
    if($inc==1){ $searchurl = $url."?".$key.'='.$value;}
    if($inc!=1){ $searchurl.= '&'.$key.'='.$value; }
   $inc++;
  endforeach;
```

when i search for the field in the db with my collection

```
$detect_duplicate = Mage::getResourceModel('savesearch/savesearch_collection');
$detect_duplicate->addFieldToFilter('content', array('like' => $searchurl));
echo $detect_duplicate->getSelect();
```

The result i got is

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `savesearch` AS `main_table` WHERE (content LIKE 'http://localhost/magento/index.php/electronics/cameras.html''cat=25&price=-100')
```

For some reason the ? is emptied. But when i replace it with other characters like * the result was

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `savesearch` AS `main_table` WHERE (content LIKE 'http://localhost/magento/index.php/electronics/cameras.html*cat=25&price=-100')
```

Can someone suggest a fix for this. I should able to search for a URL in Db to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem is when adding attributes to filter the Zend_DbAdapter `quoteInto` strips out the ?.

I would suggest using an sql wildcard for a single character _ instead of the ?. This will not match exactly ? but will instead match any single character. Note that this could return false results as the two urls that follow would both match:

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/electronics/cameras.html?cat=25&price=-100
http://localhost/magento/index.php/electronics/cameras.html*cat=25&price=-100
```

Have a look at Alan Storm's answer for a bit more detail on the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555932/magento-loadbyattribute-fails-on-question-marks

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works. I have to replace ? with _ . Can you explain how that works exactly like the search query with ? . That would be helpful.

Comment: You mean why _ work as part of the like? Or why we need to replace ? with _ in the `addFieldToFilter` call?

Comment: Need to know why '_' work as part of the like '?'

Answer (score 0):

(Again I can't comment due to my reputation)

<strike>I think it's because `?` is used as a placeholder in PDO which Magento has abstracted into their model structure.  Have you tried escaping it? Something like `\?`.</strike>

Another thing i've noticed and i'm not entirely sure if this is even relevant but theres a method `->quoteInto('AND content = ?', $urlField)`; although I've not used it.

Comment: Escaping wont work sadly :(